# How do I create a 2D plot from three columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot, contour

I'd like to make a simple 2d plot (like with imshow or contour) for some scalar data z which is dependend on two scalar input variables x and y (so z = f(x,y)).

However, I do not know the analytical function of the dependencies, I rather have all the data in three columns x,y and z in a pandas dataframe like:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'x': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
     'y': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
     'z': [30, 31, 33, 10, 8, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

This should be fairly easy, however I have not found a solution yet. Help much appreciated!
Thanks

I tried to play around with meshgrid and contour, but I do not know how to reshape my z data accordingly.

Found a solution using seaborn in [Plot a 2D Colormap/Heatmap in matplotlib with x y z data from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714388/plot-a-2d-colormap-heatmap-in-matplotlib-with-x-y-z-data-from-a-pandas-dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

d = {'x': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
     'y': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
     'z': [30, 31, 33, 10, 8, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_pivoted = df.pivot(columns='x', index='y', values='z')
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df_pivoted, cmap='RdYlGn', cbar=True, cbar_kws={'label': 'z'})
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

Gives me the plot I was looking for:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh1WC.png)

However I am still surprised that I need seaborn for that, so if anybody has a solution using pandas and matplotlib, please feel free to share.

Comment: Would a `pivot` work?

Comment: Hi @mozway, thanks that could be a solution. I'll check out pivot and report back.

Comment: Ich researched 'pivot' and found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714388/plot-a-2d-colormap-heatmap-in-matplotlib-with-x-y-z-data-from-a-pandas-dataframe which is very similar to my problem. In combination with 'pivot' I finally found the solution I am looking for (see above)